# Disabling security features to make Linux vulnerable to buffer overflow

Tags: c, linux, buffer-overflow

In order to make Linux machine vulnerable to overflow, I have to use these commands

```
sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space
```

and

```
-fno-stack-protector -z execstack -o bug bug.c
```

What is the purpose of using these two command before trying to overflow the machine? What security features they disable to cause buffer overflow?

Comment: How will you complete your homework assignment if you have broken your machine?

Comment: Sadly, I have run out of downvotes for today:(   I'll just do the close vote.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Google slave request, also about security vulnerability crap that is next-to-useless to future professional and enthusiast pogrammers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> sudo echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space

This is [Address Space Layout Randomization (ASLR)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Address_space_layout_randomization). On Windows, this is opt-in per app via the `/DYNAMICBASE` or `/HIGHENTROPYVA` switches. **The Linux command is disabling it for the whole OS, so be sure to turn it back on once you are done with your homework.** See also [Address Space Layout Randomization in Windows Vista](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michael_howard/archive/2006/05/26/address-space-layout-randomization-in-windows-vista.aspx).

> -fno-stack-protector

This is [Buffer overflow protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection). On Windows, it is enabled by building with `/GS`. See also [Compiler Security Checks In Depth](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/aa290051.aspx) for why this is useful.

> -z execstack

This is [Data Execution Protection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Execution_Prevention). On Windows, this is opt-in per app via the `/NXCOMPAT` switch. See also [/DYNAMICBASE and /NXCOMPAT](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2009/05/21/dynamicbase-and-nxcompat.aspx)

*As to exactly why you have to disable these security features, that's probably the point of your homework.*

> On Windows there is one more security mechanism which is controlled by the `/SAFESEH` linker switch. See [Preventing the Exploitation of Structured Exception Handler (SEH) Overwrites with SEHOP](http://blogs.technet.com/b/srd/archive/2009/02/02/preventing-the-exploitation-of-seh-overwrites-with-sehop.aspx) for what this is about.